# Fixed Menu & Scroll to DIV with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

im doing a page, I've manage to create a one page website, with a fixed menu.

My problem: I want to add the scrollto.element jquery to my page, already tried Smint, Ariel Flesler and Infinty.js, none worked.

Im new to jQuery but I think I can setup things with the guide/tutorial but its just not working.

Can someone help out?

**My Temporary Test Host:** http://styleeuclides.site50.net/#home

Comment: hit F12 in the browser (Chrome or IE) and there is a least 7 errors. The main one is $ is undefined. You are including jquery at the wrong place in your page. jquery needs to be included first before you use the $

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to animate a scroll to an element, the following should do it:

```
$('.button1').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop:$('element-to-scroll-to').scrollTop()
    }, 250);
});
```

Something like that should do the trick.

Comment: Example, my menu has a li with: <a href="#home">HOME</a> and I want to scroll to the page div: <div id="home">...</div>

How I should do it and where to add the code?

Comment: Where it says 'button1', give your a href a class of 'home_button', and change 'element-to-scroll-'to to #home

Comment: Have you check the page link I linked before? Can you explain using my code? in case u missed [Click Here](http://styleeuclides.site50.net/)

Comment: Make sure you include jQuery in your head tag: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" />